# Model class used as a field type in itself causes error in Ebean

Tags: java, inheritance, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm using Play Framework 2.4. I want to model a set of classes with this inheritance chain:

```
Research <- Publication <- Article
```

The problem is, I would like the Publication class to refer to the other objects of this class, like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Research extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
}

@Entity
public class Publication extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    public Publication translationOf;
}
```

This works when I don't inherit from Publication. 
When I add inheriting from Article:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Publication extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    public Publication translationOf;
}

@Entity
public class Article extends Publication { }
```

I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error with association
to [class models.research.Publication]
from [models.research.publication.Article.translationOf]. 
Is class models.research.Publication registered?
```

I thought that maybe configuring the `InheritanceType` explicity will help, but adding `@Inheritance` tag causes `NullPointerException` without any other informative nested exceptions in the stacktrace. This happens for example in this case:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "dtype", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Research extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String dtype;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("P")
public class Publication extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    public Publication translationOf;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, Publication is an @Entity. After that it's suddenly a @Mappedsuperclass

I don't understand what you want here. Do you want one publication to be linked to other publications? Because that's a ManyToMany relationship.

And for ManyToMany relationships, you need to specify the "mappedBy" argument.

Same for articles and publications. One Article could appear in many Publications and many publications could have the same article.

Unless it has to be specifically different for your setup?

EDIT: Played around with it a bit, this setup works:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Research extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Publication extends Research {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "myReferences")
    // What other publications refer to this one?
    public List<Publication> referencedBy;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "CROSS_REFERENCE",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "MY_ID")
                    },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "REFERENCER_ID")
            })
    // What publications am I referring to?
    public List<Publication> myReferences;

    // The list of articles in this publication.
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Article> articles;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Article extends Research {

    // The publications this article appears in.
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "articles")
    public List<Publication> publications;
}
```

ManyToMany relations always need have an "owner".

In the publication-to-publication case, it is the `myReferences` field. This is why the "referencedBy" field has the "mappedBy" argument in the @ManyToMany annotation.

A publication can't know ahead of time what future publications will reference them and past publications won't change to reference this new one.

So you can only ever say of a new publication which old ones it is referencing.

And which articles it contains.

You can add in both directions, but it is generally a best practice to use 1 direction and stick to it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code works. However, I don't want `Article` to inherit from `Research`. It should inherit from `Publication` (there are different kind of publications, like articles and books, which can reference each other). That's why in my second code example I change annotation of `Publication` to `@MappedSuperclass`. Adding `Article` class that inherits from `Publication` causes`java.lang.RuntimeException: Error with association to [class models.research.Publication] from [models.research.publication.Article.referencedBy]. Is class models.research.Publication registered?`

Comment: @nuoritoveri A `MappedSuperClass` is a class containing fields that every `@Entity` that inherits from it, will also have. It is not a model in the database and therefor you can't reference to it with a `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToMany` annotation. If you want to link the article to the publication, the publication must be an `@Entity`. Ebean will take care of creating the `publication_id` field in the Article table.

Comment: I couldn't force the inheritance to work, so I finally decided to use composition instead of inheritance (`Article`, `Book`, etc. have a `@OneToOne` field of type `Publication`). Your answer helped me with setting `@ManyToMany` relation. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped. I only figured that ManyToMany thing out when I tried it a few times.